# can we make global variables by defining a class variable outside of the class with "dot" operator?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

```
class abc
{
    public:
    int x;
};

abc b1;

b1.x=10;

int main()
{

}
```

why can't we write this `b1.x=10;` outside of the main function?
it shows error if we write `b1.x=10;` outside of the main function, why?

Comment: Why not try to compiling it before asking a question?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Then they should at least include the error message.  More than likely we could find a dupe target with it.

Answer (score 4):

Because, `b1.x=10;` is an *assignment statement* which cannot be present at *file scope*.

You can, however, use *initialzation* to provide the initial values. Something like

```
abc b1 = {10};
```

Comment: why do we can't define variable of a class or a non class variable outside of the function, if we can define any non class variable outside of the function to make it global variable?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is an **assignment** to a variable.  That can't be done outside of a function.

What you can do is **initialize** that variable at the time it is declared.

```
abc b1 = { 10 };
```

Comment: why do we can't define variable of a class or a class variable outside of the function, if we can define any non class variable outside of the function to make it global variable?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to put procedural statements outside any function; it's not allowed.  There are two reasons this could be confusing:

1) Maybe you're used to languages where you can have code outside any function.  In perl, for example, the whole file is a script that gets executed, and defining and calling functions is entirely a matter of choice.  Not so in C++; statements to execute go in functions.

2) `b1.x=10` may resemble a *declaration*, which indeed *could* go outside any function.  But it's not.  It is a *statement*.  By contrast outside a function saying `int x=10` is a definition (a type of declaration, which happens to include an initializer that looks very much like the assignment expression statement).

Comment: why do we can't define variable of a class or a  class variable outside of the function, if we can define any non class variable outside of the function to make it global variable?

Comment: Because one of the core principles of traditional OO design is encapsulation.  The class definition is meant to be self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, as it's too short and doesn't explain a lot, but I'll give it a go.

If you are trying to assign a value outside of function scope, that's simply not permitted by C++. C++ is not working like python/javascript where you assign values with the dot operator, and you are allowed to write them outside of scope.

If you are trying to set the class x variable as always 10 outside of scopes, you are looking for a static variable.

Comment: why do we can't define variable of a class or a class variable outside of the function, if we can define any non class variable outside of the function to make it global variable?

Comment: "defining" class variables outside of scope is not anymore defining. It's executing operations on memory blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Class members are defined inside the class, not outside:

```
class abc
{
    public:
    int x = 10;
};
```

Part of your problem is that you think `b1.x` is a class member. This is confusing classes and objects. `abc` is a class, and `abc::x` is a class member. `b1.x` is a member of an object. You can't define members of an object.

Comment: why do we can't define variable of a class or a non class variable outside of the function, if we can define any non class variable outside of the function to make it global variable?

Comment: @sampadsaha: Practically speaking, because `sizeof(class abc)` must have a value. If you can add additional members later, `sizeof` can't work.