# C - error in initializing structure with array members

Tags: arrays, c, struct, initialization, ansi-c

I want to initialize a structure I've made, but I get errors and I am unable to  understand what has caused them.
I'm working on GCC with ANSI C flag.

If someone can help me understand what the problem is, I'll very much appreciate it!

```
typedef struct _inst {
   const char *name[NUM_OF_INSTRUCTIONS];
   int codes[NUM_OF_INSTRUCTIONS];
   int validParam[NUM_OF_INSTRUCTIONS];    
 } instructions;


instructions instructionsData;

instructionsData.name[] = {"mov", "cmp", "add", "sub", "not", "clr", "lea", "inc", "dec", "jmp", "bne", "red", "prn", "jsr", "rts", "stop"};
instructionsData.codes[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
instructionsData.validParam[] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0};
```

and the errors I get from gcc are:

```
dataStructs.h:47:17: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 instructionsData.name[] = {"mov", "cmp", "add", "sub", "not", "clr", "lea", "inc", "dec", "jmp", "bne", "red", "prn", "jsr", "rts", "stop"};
                 ^
dataStructs.h:47:140: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function [-Wpedantic]
 instructionsData.name[] = {"mov", "cmp", "add", "sub", "not", "clr", "lea", "inc", "dec", "jmp", "bne", "red", "prn", "jsr", "rts", "stop"};
                                                                                                                                            ^
dataStructs.h:48:17: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 instructionsData.codes[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
                 ^
dataStructs.h:48:82: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function [-Wpedantic]
 instructionsData.codes[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
                                                                                  ^
dataStructs.h:49:17: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 instructionsData.validParam[] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0};
                 ^
dataStructs.h:49:81: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function [-Wpedantic]
 instructionsData.validParam[] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0};
```

Comment: Could you please copy-paste the code and not post screen shots?

Comment: dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41510479/2173917

Comment: @SouravGhosh although solution is the same, I think the problem is different. Not a dupe?

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is an assignment post initialization. You cannot assign arrays like that.

What you can instead do is -

```
instructions instructionData = {{"mov", "cmp" ... }, {0, 1, 2, ... }, {2, 2 ,2 ... }};
```

This initializes the entire struct in the definition.

At the same time if your struct has other fields which you do not have initial values for, you can use designated initializers -

```
instructions instructionData = {.codes={0, 1, 2, ... }};
```

This initializes all the other fields to the default initial values for the respective types like `NULL` for pointers, `0` for integers etc.

If you absolutely have to assign individual non scalar fields post initialization you can use `memcpy` as

```
memcpy(instructionData.name, &({"mov", "cmp" ... }), sizeof(({"mov", "cmp" ... })));
```

You can also use of `sizeof (instructionData.name)` but then you have to ensure that your initializer is at least as long as the field.

Comment: you're *afraid*? ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen I am *sure* ;)

Comment: thank you, it's now compiling!
but I still don't understand what the problem was...

Comment: @CrazyPhrog the problem was that you cannot assign non scalar elements using a single `=`